# .Net Core API - Route Parameters in Query String not working

Tags: .net, api, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We are in the process of upgrading our Web API to .Net Core. The API is an Employees API with Employee Search and GET endpoints as below:

```
GET /employees/{id}
GET /employees
```

For the Get endpoint, currently the both the below calls works:

```
https://example.com/employees/001
https://example.com/employees/{id}?id=001
```

After upgrading the code to .Net Core 6.0, only the below call work:

```
https://example.com/employees/001
```

The other call with id in the query string does not work. Is there a way to get both the calls working in .Net Core

Answer (score 0):

This is all how you define your routes. If you put the parameter in the route, like /employees/001, it will look for that path to determine which function to hit. So for instance I setup 2 routes that call 2 functions:

```
    [Route("Stuff/{id}")]
    public IActionResult StuffWithIDInPath(int id)
    {
        ViewData["idVal"] = id;
        return View("SomeStuff");
    }

    [Route("Stuff")]
    public IActionResult StuffWithIDInQS(int id)
    {
        ViewData["idVal"] = id;
        return View("SomeStuff");
    }
```

The first route is hit when I go to something/stuff/37

[image: Response to parameter in route]

And the second function does not have the parameter in the route, but it is also a parameter to the function, so it knows to look for it if it shows up:

[image: Response with parameter in QS]

But perhaps you want one function to handle both scenarios, and you can do that two if you just define the routes correctly for the same function.

```
    [Route("Stuff/{id}")]
    [Route("Stuff")]
    public IActionResult StuffWithIDEitherPlace(int id)
    {
        ViewData["idVal"] = id;
        return View("SomeStuff");
    }
```

In that case, either URL will go to that function, handling parameters in the route or as a querystring.

Comment: This does not work as we already have a search endpoint having the same route

Comment: What route do you want to use? And how do you want to pass the parameters? Perhaps updating the question with that will help.

Comment: I need to use a Get By Id Route -> /employees/{id} which should accept both
https://example.com/employees/001, 
https://example.com/employees/{id}?id=001
This used to work in .Net Framework code.

Comment: And you said the example.com/employees route is already "taken?" I am not sure how full framework worked before, frankly it shouldn't have allowed two routes to filter through one, but if something is already using that URL, you can't use it again.

Comment: @SillyJohn I am also having the same issues as you and based on my research, you're right, back in .NET 4 it did work but NOW it doesn't in .NET Core so I'm also looking for a work around. If you find one b4 I do, please share! TX

Answer (score 0):

your action route attribute should have id as an optional parameter

```
     [HttpGet("~/employees/{id?}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int? id)
```

or if  a controller is Employees

```
 public class Employees : ApiController
..........
    [HttpGet("id?}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int? id)
```

Comment: This seems to be not working. I am using .Net Core 6.0 framework. I am getting the error - {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"00-62dd6653938ff33fa3f6a5a35f09e1b4-5fe2142d49d4773d-00","errors":{"id":["The value '{id}' is not valid."]}}

Comment: @SillyJohn Can you show your full url pls?

Comment: I tried the below 3 - 
http://localhost:5271/WeatherForecast/4   -> This works;
http://localhost:5271/employees/id?id=4   -> This does not work;
http://localhost:5271/employees/%7Bid%7D?id=4     -> This does not work;

Comment: @SillyJohn You can use localhost:5271/WeatherForecast?id=4 too. localhost:5271/employees/id?id=4  doesn' t make any sense,  and localhost:5271/employees/%7Bid%7D?id=4  doesn't make any sense too.

Comment: Ya only  http://localhost:5271/WeatherForecast/4 makes sense. But the issue is, all the three used to work in .Net Framework and we are actually upgrading from .Net Framework to .Net Core 6.0 and it will be a breaking change for the consumers. Just thinking if there is a workaround

Comment: @SillyJohn YOu have to post the real url in your question. For example I can  not see  localhost:5271/employees/%7Bid%7D?id=4  and anybody will tell you that only a weird person, who doesnt know any software development, could create this route.

Answer (score 0):

This worked as I ended up merging my .NET Framework Get() & Get(string lat, string lng) like this. If I was creating this from scratch, I wouldn't do it this way but I have an IOS app that will need to get updated after I migrate my API over to .NET Core.

```
// Get All Restaurants OR Get By Latitude/Longitude
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<LocationListViewModel>>> Get(string lat = "", string lng = "")
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lat) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(lng))
    {
        return await _locationService.GetRestaurantsAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        return await _locationService.GetRestaurantsByLatLngAsync(lat, lng);
    }
}
```